# Should this sentence use the singular "is" or the plural "are"?

Tags: grammatical-number

On any given day an average of 400 children is receiving care in one of seven major programs providing home health care, respite services, medical day programming, early intervention therapies, well and sick health care at the Family Healthcare Campus on the grounds of Child Haven, in our High Risk Infants clinic, and/or in our Behavioral Health Program. Many children receive multiple services

Comment: Definitely 'are'. But the bigger problem with the sentence is that it's ridiculously long and needs to be broken up.

Comment: The noun "average" (when used with the article "a") is number-transparent in that the number of the whole NP for verb agreement purposes is determined by the number of the noun that is complement to "of" (called the oblique). Since "average" selects only plural obliques, the verb should also be plural, i.e. "are".

Comment: More than one child is receiving. Ergo, the subject is plural and the verb plural.

Comment: @NigelJ The head of the NP "an average of 400 children" is the singular noun "average" so the subject is strictly speaking singular. But the NP that is complement of the preposition "of", i.e. "400 children" determines the verb-form.

Comment: @BillJ My definition of 'subject' is somewhat old school and conceptual.

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Use "...children receive..."

The present continuous ("is/are receiving") should be used for recurring events that are not expected to continue into the foreseeable future. If this were the correct usage of the present continuous, it would be plural, since *children* is a collective noun.

The present simple ("receive") [should be used](https://www.englishgrammar.org/simple-present-present-continuous-tense-differences/) (for want of a better reference) for recurring events that you expect will continue to occur in the foreseeable future.

> On any given day an average of 400 children receive care in one of seven major programs...

You got it right in the last sentence:

> Many children receive multiple services...

I agree with eyeballfrog's second point, that the first sentence needs to be simplified. Maybe try:

> On any given day an average of 400 children receive care in one of seven major programs at the Family Healthcare Campus (Child Haven), in our High Risk Infants clinic, and in our Behavioral Health Program. Many children receive receive multiple services[...] Service include home health care, respite services, medical day programming, early intervention therapies, and well and sick health care.

Comment: OK. I frequently hear statements like the original sentence (with the correct conjugation, of course). Maybe it's for recurring events we wish wouldn't continue, e.g. "Hundreds of people are being housed in homeless shelters every day."

Comment: @Barmar, I've now responded to three of your comments, after which you've deleted all three, so I'll let someone else address this one. If you have a new question, please ask as a new question in the relevant forum.

Comment: I deleted the comments because you addressed them, so they're no longer needed.

Comment: That makes sense actually. My apologies.

Comment: @Barmar, yeah the rules for use of the present continuous and whether something is expected to continue are a little vague. In this case, it looks like some marketing copy for a hospital system, so they likely hope that children continue to receive care there. One exception I can think of is if the facility is closing for some reason. Then present continuous is correct.

Comment: @Barmar Good point. 'Are receiving' stresses a current situation that is not desirable, albeit that it is necessary, and that all concerned would rather the whole thing ceased.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance. I think restructuring the sentence is the best way to go. I tend to forget that option when I struggle with a sentence where the "rules" of grammar are a little vague.